# Assign the value of another column to the empty cells of a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have the following DataFrame in pandas:

| code | city | district |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | London | Westminster |
| 03 | Madrid | NaN |
| 04 | Rome | Trevi |
| 07 | Berlin | NaN |
| 08 | Barcelona | Badalona |

For the `district` column if the row value is nan, I want to assign it the same value it has in its `city` attribute. Example:

| code | city | district |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | London | Westminster |
| 03 | Madrid | Madrid |
| 04 | Rome | Trevi |
| 07 | Berlin | Berlin |
| 08 | Barcelona | Badalona |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `fillna()` and pass the other column name:

```
df['district'] = df['district'].fillna(df['city'])
```

If the value is not Null (which I suggest to have it Null for best practices) but an empty string, you can evaluate a condition, so that:

```
df['district'] = np.where(df['district'] == '',df['city'],df['district'])
```

Comment: If they are nan, edited.

Comment: It should work with the first approach then, thanks for the clarification